# Excel: Finding first occurence of date where a value reaches below -4500

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a running cashflow and I would like to include an overview in a dashboard of when the first occuring date in the future is where the cashflow reaches below -4500.

In cell A I have the running dates (past and future)
In cell I is the running cashflow sum (past and future)

I've used index and match with no success as well as Vlookup. Either I get a date in the past or I get a #N/A result.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your data sorted by date? Show your data sample, formulas you tried and expected result

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the info you presented not too detailed this is a simple example of reach the first date.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue despite the fact that I see I didn't give adequate information.